# Datapicker SOMENTE Ano e Mês parando no mês

Tags: bootstrap, datapicker

Estou desenvovlendo uma solução que preciso otimizar o tempo para alimentar o sistema com datas, que por muitas vezes é muito repetitivo.

PROBLEMA: Um dos campos que insere data, eu só quero o ano e o mês. Eu formatei ele pra receber ano e mês, mas o usuário precisa chegar até o dia para o input receber o ano e o mês, e isso não é necessário. Teoricamente poderia resolver isso com os atributos "minViewMode" e "maxViewMode" do datapicker, mas o mesmo inicia na janela "mês" mas não reconhece o "maxViewMode: 1" para parar por ali, proessegue até a seleção do dia.

```js
$('#database').datepicker({
    language: 'pt-BR',
    startView: 1,
    minViewMode: 1,
    maxViewMode: 1,
    format: 'MM/yyyy',
    /* 
        //beforeShowDay:unavailable
        //beforeShowDay: onlyPastdays
        autoclose: true,
        minViewMode: 1,
        format: 'mm/yyyy' */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group col-lg-12">
  <span class="input-group-addon botao-label">Data-Base:</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="database" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar, acredito estar no caminho! http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/13475/ Abs!!